# Why do I get an error when I try to execute a query with parameters in postgreSQL?

Tags: django, postgresql, django-orm

The db is PostgreSQL. When I try to execute a query with parameters, such as this one

```
cursor.execute("""
    SELECT u.username, up.description, 
        ts_rank_cd(to_tsvector(coalesce(username,'')|| coalesce(description,'')) , to_tsquery('%s')) as rank

        FROM auth_user u INNER JOIN pm_core_userprofile up on u.id = up.user_id
        WHERE to_tsvector(coalesce(username,'')|| coalesce(description,'')) @@ to_tsquery('%s')
        ORDER BY rank DESC;
    """, ["hello","hello"])
```

Django complains of a **ProgrammingError**, adding **syntax error at or near the parameter** (in this example, "**hello**"). Here's the part of the Django generated SQL statement that the error comes from:

```
to_tsquery('E'hello'')
```

Even if I copy-paste it to a postgreSQL shell, I get the syntax error. If I omit the 'E' part, it works. What should I make of it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ozgur,

Try

```
to_tsquery(%s)
```

instead of

```
to_tsquery('%s')
```

Comment: Thanks! This is embarrassing, I think I better take a vacation asap :)

Comment: Would have been more embarrassing if I had guessed wrong...I'm more used to SQL Server syntax. ;)

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are missing a ' after the E.

Comment: The E stuff is put there by Django ORM, I just pass a string.